# Prevent colorbox from indenting text

Tags: tables, indentation, colorbox

I have a table with entries in the first column to be aligned to the left of the page. I have a colorbox around one of the entries, which is causing the text to be slightly indented. Is there a way to prevent this?

A picture showing the problem:

[image]

And the markup I am using:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{mygrey}{rgb}{0.1, 0.14, 0.12}
\definecolor{darkjunglegreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.26, 0.15}
\usepackage[
top    = 0.608cm,
bottom = 1.1cm,
left   = 1.20cm,
right  = 1.10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\semiLarge{\@setfontsize\semiLarge{13.22}{17.38}}
\begin{document}
    \sloppy
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
        \textbf{\LARGE \textcolor{mygrey}{REAL NAME}}  & \large{email@realemail.com}\\
        \colorbox{mygrey!11}{\textbf{\semiLarge \textcolor{smokyblack}{Employed Professional}}} &  \large{555-555-5555 - New York, NY}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can either set \fboxsep to 0pt, or use \hspace(-\fboxsep} to compensate.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you, I did not know about the fboxsep command, I just used it and this removed the indentation, but it also raised the vertical height of the box. Is there a way to remove the indentation without adjusting the height?

Comment: Did you try the negative \hspace yet.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Negative hspace worked a treat, thank you. If you want to make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\colorbox` macro from xcolor adds an `\fboxsep` border (actually it uses `\fbox`).  This compensates for the excess horizontal space.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{mygrey}{rgb}{0.1, 0.14, 0.12}
\definecolor{darkjunglegreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.26, 0.15}
\usepackage[
top    = 0.608cm,
bottom = 1.1cm,
left   = 1.20cm,
right  = 1.10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\semiLarge{\@setfontsize\semiLarge{13.22}{17.38}}
\begin{document}
    \sloppy
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
        \textbf{\LARGE \textcolor{mygrey}{REAL NAME}}  & \large{email@realemail.com}\\
        \hspace{-\fboxsep}\colorbox{mygrey!11}{\textbf{\semiLarge \textcolor{smokyblack}{Employed Professional}}} &  \large{555-555-5555 - New York, NY}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```